# Book: Starts in a scavenger pod cleaning up earth orbit

Tags: story-identification, books, hard-sci-fi, space-station

A few years back I read a book which I'd like to look up again:

- It starts in a ship.
- It's on a tether from a space station (I think).
- Its job is to scavenge (and clean) debris from earth orbit.
- It's a one man operation.
- He snags something unusual, apparently not of earthly origin which sets up the opening premise.

Comment: You stopped reading just when the man snagged something unearthly? So you have no idea what kind of thing it was, or what happened afterward?

Comment: How many years back is "a few"? Less than 10? More than 20?

Comment: Less than ten, I believe, although the book itself could be a bit older.  I'd guess less than 10-15 to be safe.

Comment: I did read it but, at the moment, I can't recall the rest of the book.  It was a great opening and I'd like to re-read it which is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're recalling the opening chapter of *[Existence](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1435600)* (2012) by David Brin.

Gerald Livingstone works in a one-man pod attached to a space station:

> Gerald floated in a crystal shell, perched at the end of a long boom, some distance from the space station *Endurance*.

He is an orbital junk collector who uses an electromagnetically-manipulated tether to collect debris:

> *The bola is my arm.*
> *The grabber is my hand.*
> *Magnetic is the lever that I turn.*
> *A planet is my fulcrum.*
>
> Most days, the little chant helped Gerald to focus on his job - that of a glorified garbageman.

He snags an unusual object:

> Rushing towards rendezvous, the bola's camera spied something glittery, vaguely oval in shape, gleaming with a pale blueness that pulsed like something eager.
>
> Gerald's hand *was* the grabber, turning a fielder's mitt of splayed fingers, reaching as the object loomed suddenly.
>
> *Don't flinch*, he chided ancient intuitions while preparing to snatch whatever this hurtling thing might be.
>
> *Relax.  It never hurts.*
>
> Only this time - in a strange and puzzling way - it did.

Which, when it's investigated later seems to be trying to communicate, but in no known language or symbology.